# WordPress: one condition for multiple values but one key when querying with custom fields

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I am working on some kind of booking extension for a custom post type in Wordpress. The admin can choose the dates when the object is booked. The booked date is saved as a new custom field with the key "booking" and the date in the format "yymmdd". So one object can have multiple custom fields with the same key, but multiple values.

Now I need to query the objects that are available for a specific date. The following is one of my last attempts.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'object',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'booking',
            'value' => array('131020', '131021', '131022'),
            'compare' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

From my logic, I am searching for an object that is available from 131020 to 131022. What WordPress sees to do though is comparing each of the available multiple values individually. So if the element is booked on 131019 and on 131020, WordPress still returns it as available, because 131019 is not in the values above.

What I need is a logic that say "if none of the multiple values is among the mentioned numbers, return the post"

I also tried using just a serialized array for all of the dates, but this didn’t work either. I am sure there might be a simple trick, but after doing a lot of research I am stuck here.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After many other approaches, I finally ended up with the following "solution".
I saved all the dates as an array and was using NOT LIKE for each of the dates that needed to be available. The code from above would look like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'object',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'booking',
            'value' => '131020',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'booking',
            'value' => '131021',
            'compare' => 'NOT IN'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'booking',
            'value' => '131022',
            'compare' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Note `relation => 'AND'` at the beginning. As I understand, this is the default, but in case you use 'OR' here this wouldn’t work either.

Still happy about any comment on both of the approaches.